# Iterator remove throws ConcurrentException

Tags: java, iterator, concurrentmodification

Was trying to implement in-place purge on a list.

```
        Iterator<Integer> itr = ls.iterator();
        for (Integer x : ls) {
            int count = 0;
            while(itr.hasNext()){
                if (itr.next().equals(x)) {
                    count++;
                    if (count > 1) {
                        itr.remove();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Exception in thread "main" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException

```
        Iterator<Integer> iterator = numbers.iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            if (iterator.next() == 1) {
                iterator.remove(); // Doesn't throw exception
            }
        }
```

However, with just one loop thought it doesn't. Why ?

what is the reasoning for this behavior

Comment: `for (Integer x : ls)` is iterating over the list (using a second `Iterator`.) Inside the loop, the list is being modified by the first `Iterator`, that is, not by the second, so the second one is invalidated (used in the `for`)

Comment: You can't remove from a list while iterating over it, which is what you're doing.

Comment: [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ArrayList.html) of `ArrayList`, I am assuming `ls` is one: "*The iterators returned by this class's iterator and listIterator methods are fail-fast: if the list is structurally modified at any time after the iterator is created, in any way except through the iterator's own remove or add methods, the iterator will throw a ConcurrentModificationException.*"

Comment: this is not in-place though. 

@Andy Turner has provided in-place purge algo below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two iterators over `ls` here:

- The one created explicitly via `ls.iterator()`;
- The one created implicitly via `for (Integer x : ls)`.

If you call `remove()` on the first iterator, it invalidates the second iterator, meaning any invocations of `next()` on the second iterator cause (or are prone to causing) a `ConcurrentModificationException` to be thrown.

---

A possible way to do an in-place deduplication might be like this:

```
int dst = 0;
for (Integer x : ls) {
  if (!ls.subList(0, dst).contains(x)) {
    ls.set(dst++, x);
  }
}
ls.subList(dst, ls.size()).clear();
```

This shifts elements that haven't been seen before to the left in the array; and then removes all other elements from the array afterwards.

Changing the list in the loop doesn't result in a `ConcurrentModificationException` because there is no structural modification to the list.

Answer (score 2):

In order to look in to this problem we need to study how the `Java enhanced for loop` works internally.

Java enhanced for loop is internally using a `Fail Fast Iterator` which uses an internal flag named `modCount` (This updats each time when ever the collection is modified) to track the structure of collection manipulated or not. If there is any change then it's throwing `ConcurrentModificationException`.

Please see the following synonym code for the enhanced for loop.

```
 List<Integer> ls = Arrays.asList(1,2,3);

 for (Integer x : ls) {

 }
```

Synonymous code with internal code structure

```
for (Iterator<Integer> itr = ls.iterator(); itr.hasNext();) {
   Integer x = itr.next(); 
}
```

Because of the above code structure, the enhanced for loop is not allowing to remove elements while iterating.

Even though there is no explicit reference to the for iterator to call the remove() method, if remove() method is called on List then ConcurrentModificationException is firing.

Finally, the reason for `ConcurrentModificationException` should be you are calling remove() method on the iterator `itr`, which works on the same list `ls` while invoking enhanced for loop related to same list `ls`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another possibility that avoids a concurrent mod exception. To remove duplicates use a set.

```
 List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(List.of("A","B","C","D","A","B","B","E"));
 Set<String> set = new LinkedHashSet<>();
 set.addAll(list);
 System.out.println(set);
```

prints

```
[A, B, C, D, E]
```

Note: Any set could be used.  A linked hash set preserves insertion order.

Answer (score 0):

There is one hiccup I ran into implementing this algo

purgeInplace(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 1))

throws

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
        at java.base/java.util.AbstractList.remove(AbstractList.java:169)
        at java.base/java.util.AbstractList$Itr.remove(AbstractList.java:389)
        at java.base/java.util.AbstractList.removeRange(AbstractList.java:600)
        at java.base/java.util.AbstractList$SubList.removeRange(AbstractList.java:813)     
        at java.base/java.util.AbstractList.clear(AbstractList.java:245)
        at PurgeUtil.purgeInplace(PurgeUtil.java:25)
        at PurgeUtil.main(PurgeUtil.java:15)
```

However,
purgeInplace(new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 1)));

works fine.

ps. Couldn't put this under a comment because of word limit.

Comment: * implementing algo suggested by Andy Turner below.